# How stable is Remdesivir when vial vacuum is broken and/or it is reconstituted with sterile water?

Tags: organic-chemistry, drugs, medicinal-chemistry, pharmacology

I was recently looking at how long can Remdesivir be stored in its different forms.

I came up across several articles provided by the [FDA](https://www.fda.gov/media/137566/download) and [Gilead Sciences](https://www.gilead.com/-/media/files/pdfs/remdesivir/eua-fact-sheet-for-hcps.pdf) and [others](https://www.chkd.org/uploadedFiles/Documents/COVID-19/remdesivir%20CHKD%20guideline%204-3.pdf).

What caught my eye was the fact that after you reconstitute Remdesivir with sterile water you cannot store it at all! The manual and articles provided by numerous sources all say the same thing. they clearly state that you should use the reconstituted solution right away, meaning combine it with a NaCl serum. The serum then can be stored for up to 48 hours inside the fridge (no more than that). As stated by the FDA article and also another [article](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/documents/other/summary-compassionate-use-remdesivir-gilead_en.pdf) by the EU medicines agency this is mainly because of bacterial and parasitical contamination, which is irrelevant to this question.

> Care should be taken during admixture to prevent inadvertent microbial contamination. As there is no preservative or bacteriostatic agent present in this product, an aseptic technique must be used in the preparation of the final parenteral solution. It is always recommended to administer intravenous medication immediately after preparation when possible.
>
> -- FDA

> Chemical and physical in-use stability has been demonstrated for 24 hours at 25°C. From a
> microbiological point of view, unless the method of opening/reconstitution/dilution precludes the risk of
> microbial contamination, the product should be used immediately. If not used immediately, in-use
> storage tomes and conditions are the responsibility of the user.
>
> -- European Medicines Agency

So my question is putting aside the problem of keeping the product aseptic, How long does the Remdesivir molecule itself manage to be stable inside a vial reconstituted with sterile water. (Note that the vial vacuum has also been broken)

It would also be helpful to describe the chemical processes/reactions that happen, causing the product to lose its efficacy.

Comment: Without speaking to a specific drug, the storage times may be "generic", with a large safety margin. I.E.,  A particular mRNA vaccine might not have safe storage checked individually, but  be given a storage plan found suitable for similar mRNA vaccines. Note that after release, some of these vaccines have had storage options change!

Comment: I can see an apple going "bad" after several hours, however, I imagine an apple being a living thing that dies while outside. but, I don't know how a chemical compound which is a dead thing such as Remdesivir can go bad.

Comment: From the FDA document you link to : "Care should be taken during admixture to prevent inadvertent microbial contamination. **As there is no preservative or bacteriostatic agent** present in this product, aseptic technique must be used in preparation of the final parenteral solution. It is always recommended to administer intravenous medication immediately after preparation when possible." Basically you want to avoid contamination because it is administered intravenously - see the highlighted part above.

Comment: I admit it sounds mysterious. Presumably the vial is not an aseptic container once vacuum has been breached, whereas the saline bags are considered somewhat safer. But that is an opinion. You may want to ask this over at medical sciences SE: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BuckThorn Could one, smear some cotton with alcohol and tape it on top of the vial in order to avoid contamination?

Comment: I actually asked this from several doctors, however, all of them were clueless as to why it is so, most of them were like I could try to store it inside the fridge and see what happens. Some drugs such as Ceftriaxone actually do go bad, turning from white to yellow and then orange to red after reconstitution and storage inside the fridge, however this did not happen with Remdesivir and it managed to keep its clear color through 5 days. However, I imagine color is not a reliable indication of whether a drug has gone bad or not.

Comment: Treating it this way might be standard best practice ("better safe than sorry"). "Go bad" can mean many things. Remdesivir is a prodrug and is supposed to undergo enzyme-catalyzed conversion into an active drug.  Going bad might mean a reaction like oxidation or hydrolysis or some unwanted phase transition (precipitation) coupled to a chemical change. The fact that saline is ok makes it mysterious. I suspect it minimizes bacterial contamination. I cannot advise handling it in any way other than what is suggested by the manufacturer.

Comment: If you put aside the issue with keeping the product aseptic, there is a potentially interesting chemistry question here: how stable is remdesivir the molecule if the vacuum seal is broken, or if sterile water is added. I can't say what kind of reception such a question will get, but I think people here can at least guess that just by looking at the molecular structure.

Comment: @BuckThorn If you think I forgot to add anything please feel free to edit.

Comment: @ATheCoder Well at least the focus is on chemistry now and I (personally) find it useful. Note that I found an answer by searching for the keywords "remdesivir stability testing", see eg https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjAt_3bpb7wAhVXAhAIHdm_DbsQFjAEegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F1999-4923%2F12%2F11%2F1002%2Fpdf&usg=AOvVaw1Zc2FAtVfn_-En6qrJsITp Look into the introduction of that article and you will find your answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124057/discussion-between-buck-thorn-and-athecoder).